# Geometric progression having the first and last values and the number of steps

Tags: math

Here's the task at hand:

- I have the first and last values (a range from 0 to 100)
- I have the number of steps (20)
- I need to find values for all 20 steps

So, a simple arithmetic progression would be to use the difference of 5 for each step. However, I want the difference between steps 19-20 to be the biggest and the difference between steps 1-2 to be the smallest, with the rest of values progressively between the two.

What are my options? How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Why did you ask this on Stack Overflow and not [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Sorry guys - I first posted it on Programming puzzles and was suggested by moderators to post on Stack Overflow, not Mathematics. I will delete this question here and repost on Mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Ratio between successive terms in a progression with first value `A`, last value `B` and number of steps `N` is `r = (B/A)^(1/N)`